# How to throw an exception when setting property in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

My stub should throw an exception when its property (a double) is set (to any value).
How can I accomplish this using Rhino Mocks 3.5?

I tried this:

```
        var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyInterface>();
        myMock.Stub(x => x.MyProperty).Throw(new Exception());
```

But that gives me:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : You are trying to set an expectation on a property that was defined to use PropertyBehavior.
Instead of writing code such as this: mockObject.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty).Return(42);
You can use the property directly to achieve the same result: mockObject.SomeProperty = 42;
```

But in this case I am not talking about setting and getting a simple value, it should throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace with `MockRepository.GenerateMock,`

This version has problem with `GenerateStub`,

```
var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyInterface>();
myMock.Stub(x => x.MyProperty).Throw(new Exception());
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything I should know about GenerateMock or can simply replace all my GenerateStub's to GenerateMock?

Comment: I'am happy to help you Emile , you adapt according to your need, in this case it must